# how to set up guaranteed io with XFS?

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs

According to wikipedia XFS is capable to guarantee the rate of IO. How can I setup this under Linux (more specifically Centos 5.5)? Or does that only apply for IRIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quoting](http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2012-07/msg00432.html) Dave Chinner:

```
   Linux doesn't support GRIO. It's an Irix only thing, and that
    required special hardware support for bandwidth reservation, special
    frame schedulers in the IO path, etc.
```